# Changing a Dataset for a visual in AWS Quick Sight

Tags: dataset, data-visualization, bar-chart, analysis, amazon-quicksight

I am new to Quicksight and trying to change the dataset for a cloned visual.

I have created one analysis in AWS Quicksight which contains 6 different datasets from the same Datasource. See below:

[image]

There are two tabs (report 1 / report 2) in the analysis. I have cloned the below visual with Dataset: "Arora Waterfalls Website..." from Report 2 to Report 1.

[image]

But when I try to change the dataset from "Arora Waterfalls Website..." to "Arora All Webinar..." for the cloned visual in Report 1, the visual gets unselected and when I click on it shows the same dataset again: "Arora - Waterfalls Website...":

[image]

[image]

To conclude, is there any way that we can change the dataset for a cloned visual in QuickSight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change a dataset for a visual after it has been added to the Analysis.

You will need to select the dataset you want to use, add a new visual and rebuild the chart as required.

A second suggestion: looking at your data sets, you seem to be pulling in different views/tables into multiple different datasets from one data source. If possible I recommend combining the different tables into one dataset, joining them together during ingestion. This will give you more flexibility duplicating views. Working with multiple datasets has number of limitations. This will help avoid the problem you are having trying to duplicate a visual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but these 6 datasets are giving 6 different reports and then being combined in one report. These datasets have no relation in terms of output reports. Can we make two different tables in a data set like a table 1 & table 2 having no relation with each other?

Comment: One more clarification that I need is if I have 2 or more visuals for the same analysis tab, does each visual query the data (as mentioned in the dataset) separately to the data source or fetched at once (being managed by Quick Sight) and used on visuals where requested? Currently, it takes a lot of time to load the visuals. . .